# SQl Server not connecting

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using visual studio 2012 and SQL Server 2008 R2...

My Connection String is 
Data Source=MCPL-PRINT-PC\SCMSQLSERVER;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=SCM_DB;Integrated Security=True

Now i want to use this connection string in the network, so that i can use my application in my office network from any PC.

My PC IP is 192.168.75.9

I also tried to configure the TCP/IP protocols and Configuration in SQL Server Configuration Manager. But the Configuration Manager Show the Remote Call Procedure Failed.

Please suggest me. what should i do to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please update the question with the complete error message you get. Also did it work before you enabled TCP/IP ? in that case exactly what did you change?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you'll need:

- First, make sure the SQL server is listening on TCP.
- If you want to use the instance name `SCMSQLSERVER` then you also need to make sure the SQL Browser service is started. (if not make sure the instance is listening on the default port 1433)

After this make sure the firewall lets the services through.